# how to stop firing a keyDown event that are being called multiple times after one click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, keydown

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (renderBall) {
        if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
            setBallPosition({
                ...ballPosition,
                left: parseInt(ballPosition.left) - 5 + 'px',
            });
        }

        //  arrow up
        else if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
            setBallPosition({
                ...ballPosition,
                top: parseInt(ballPosition.top) - 5 + 'px',
            });
        }

        //  arrow right
        else if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
            setBallPosition({
                ...ballPosition,
                left: parseInt(ballPosition.left) + 5 + 'px',
            });
        }

        //  arrow down
        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
            setBallPosition({
                ...ballPosition,
                top: parseInt(ballPosition.top) + 5 + 'px',
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Here's the problem: when I press up or down key, it fires more than 1 times instead of single time. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I see `keyup` in your code, where is `keydown`?

Comment: Show us the full code please - chances are that you are not removing the event listeners on the `useEffect` cleanup.

Comment: where is addEventListener being called? It's possible you are adding many duplicate event listeners. You can see all the registered listeners in the developer tools panel.

Comment: sorry while testing i changed to keyup but same problem in both

Comment: Can you please provide more code? There is not enough info in this code block to identify what is wrong.